# Need help understanding operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I'm trying to implement a structure which is basically a custom made hash table containing either nothing (NULL) or a pointer to a binary search tree object.

Anyway, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do some things, such as setting the hash table, which is an array to NULL, and also memcpy'ing BST objects from one table to another.

```
BST *prevData;
BST *currData;
```

As I understand it, I think I have to overload the = and == operators to allow setting array elements to NULL, is this correct? I'm really unclear about how to implement all this, but going on examples from Google, I've got:

```
BST& BST :: operator= (int null);
bool BST :: operator== (int null);
```

The == operator overload is to check whether a specific array index is equal to NULL. I'm assuming I need some additional code, rather than just the prototypes, and this is where I come unstuck.

The second point is memcpy, which I'm not being allowed to do by the compiler.

```
memcpy(prevData[x], currData[x], sizeof(BST) * height);
```

Complains about

> error C2664: 'memcpy' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'BST' to 'void *' No
>   user-defined-conversion operator
>   available that can perform this
>   conversion, or the operator cannot be
>   called

If you need more information, I'd be happy to fill you in.

Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: memcpy() calls in C++ code... that smells...

Comment: coudl you show us all your code for the function `BST& BST :: operator= (int null);`

Comment: I don't have code, as I mentioned above, I'm not sure what I should be overloading here, do you have any good examples of how this should be done (specifically, setting a custom-object array to NULL).

Comment: Also, fill me in on the best way of copying an object in C++ please. The sample code I was given for this project initially used memcpy() for a boolean array, so I assumed this was fine.

Comment: You cannot overload an operator to check for a _specific value_ (`null`) in C++. Either I'm misunderstanding you or you're misunderstanding operator overloading. Can you show us how you want to _use_ the operators that you attempt to overload?

Comment: Hmm, OK, so basically I need an array that is initially empty, but is populated by binary search tree objects. I'm basically writing a Game of Life app that takes the coordinates of live cells, hashes their position (to create an array index), and places them in a binary search tree at that index (which is used for collisions).

I just had a thought (it's late so I'm not thinking especially well), that I could just add an empty BST object in each index, then if I need to know if it's empty, check the number of nodes.

Comment: So that problem is solved. How can I then copy the contents of one array of BST objects, to another identical one (I keep two arrays, one with the current game state, and one with the currently-being-modified state)?

Comment: Ahh, never mind, copy constructors are the way to go I think, guess I should read my notes more. Thanks to all :)

Comment: @shrodes: Yes for copying your BST objects, you should implement copy constructors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand it, I think I have to
>   overload the = and == operators to
>   allow setting array elements to NULL,
>   is this correct?

No, not at all. You have described an array of `BST *` pointers, not of `BST` objects. NULL is already a valid value for a pointer to take, you don't need to change any C++ behaviour:

```
BST *array[LENGTH]; // LENGTH > 1
array[0] == NULL;
array[0] == new BST; // but watch for memory leaks!
array[1] == array[0];
array[0] == NULL; // now moved the array[0] pointer to array[1]
```

Any time you have an array of pointers, memory management becomes tricky, and it becomes important to consider smart pointers such as `shared_ptr`.

EDIT: as discussed in the comments, a better solution is to have some sort of null BST value:

```
class BST {
    bool isNull_;
    BST() : isNull_(true) {}
    bool isNull() { return isNull_; }
    // rest of class definition...
};
```

now, you have an "empty" BST value for which `bst.isNull_` is true. The default value is a null value. So if you create an empty vector:

```
std::vector<BST> vec = std::vector<BST>(10);
```

this will initialise to 10 null BSTs. The same is true for the `new[]` array allocation operator.

> The second point is memcpy, which I'm
>   not being allowed to do by the
>   compiler.
>
> ```
> memcpy(prevData[x], currData[x], sizeof(BST) * height);
> ```

Don't do that! It's wrong for a number of reasons, but mainly because it's a legacy C function, not suitable for C++ classes; and because you're copying one item, not a block of them.

To copy one item, use `operator=`:

```
currData[x] = prevData[x];
```

The C++ function for copying block data is `std::copy`. One reason to use it is that it can recognise overloaded `operator=` assignment operators, while `memcpy` can't. Example:

```
std::copy(prevData, prevData + LENGTH, currData);
```

(I assume you want to copy *from* `prevData` *to* `currData` like I've done here, rather than the other way around like you did for `memcpy`?)

Comment: For the first part, I assume you meant array[0] = NULL; as this is what I wanted to do. I can't get it working the way you say it should though. I am using a BST * object, but setting it equal to NULL gives me the error
"error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)" which made me think I had to use operator overloading to begin with.

Comment: @shrodes: that's very odd. If NULL is the appropriate macro (which should just be `0`), you can assign NULL to any pointer. Perhaps you have `NULL` set to some funny value? What happens if you do `array[0] = 0;`?

Comment: Think I figured this out, I need to change to:
BST **prevData;
and initialise the arrays to:
data = new BST*[some_size];?

Comment: I was doing data = new BST[some_size] which was just making an array of objects, not an array of pointers to an object. I think this is right, but some confirmation would be good :)

Comment: @shrodes: I'm a bit nervous about this. You need to be very careful about memory management if you use a dynamically-allocated array of dynamically-allocated objects. You should really put it all into smart pointers, but if you can't use the STL or Boost, that's not an option. Perhaps you should create a "NULL value" for your object, to allow your objects to represent an empty state? Implement `set_null()` and `is_null()` methods.

Comment: @shrodes: ... then instead of an array of pointers, you can just use an array of BST objects, and use `set_null()` to null them, or create a constant `BST_NULL` and use `array[0] = BST_NULL` to null the object. On reflection, I think this is a better arrangement entirely.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to add an empty BST object (these are added to later) to each index in the array, and check this instead of checking NULL?

Yep, that makes sense, thanks for your help with all this!

Comment: @shrodes: and if you make the empty BST object the result of the default constructor `BST()`, you don't even need to initialise the array to BST_NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't homework (that was your tag?) I'd recommend a single unordered_map or map.  You're conception of this isn't coming together yet - best to simplify it and tackle one thing at a time rather than biting off more than you can chew.  If you want a hash map of trees, I suggest you start building that from the C++ STL containers that you can rely on to work, then - if you're not supposed to use them for this task - replace them one by one making sure you keep the high-level usage/tests working as you do it.  That means:

```
typedef vector<map<T> > Container;
Container container;
```

You can use container.resize(n) to fill the container with n empty maps, or to grow the container from some previous size to a new one with the extra maps being empty.

Really, start with that.  Then if you have to as an exercise, implement each of the vector and map independently, and test their usage with simple indepedent test cases before slotting them back into your hybrid hash map.

It may sound like I'm being a bit harsh, so lets work through a bit of your question to see some of the mis-conceptions of which I spoke:

> Anyway, I'm having trouble figuring
>   out how to do some things, such as
>   setting the hash table, which is an
>   array to NULL, and also memcpy'ing BST
>   objects from one table to another.

My advice is keep things simple and do what's obvious and clean.  If you must use an array and not a vector, then if it's on the stack:

```
X* buckets[N];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof buckets / sizeof buckets[0]; ++i)
    array[i] = NULL;
```

If it's on the heap:

```
X** p_buckets = new X*[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    array[i] = NULL;
```

This is slower than memset(), but it's simple and understandable, and gets you in the habit of thinking about looping over your container, doing the operations you want.  There are more C++ ways to this, but it's harder to use those same styles of iteration for other arbitrary tasks, so stick to this until you're totally comfortable with it.

> BST *prevData; 
>   BST *currData;
>
> As I understand it, I think I have to overload the = and == operators to allow setting
>   array elements to NULL, is this correct? I'm really unclear about how to implement all
>   this, but going on examples from Google, I've got:
>
> BST& BST :: operator= (int null); 
>   bool BST :: operator== (int null); 
>   The == operator overload is to check whether a specific array index is equal to NULL.
>   I'm assuming I need some additional code, rather than just the prototypes, and this is
>   where I come unstuck.

You've got two pointers to BSTs.  Your hash tables are an array of such objects, but it's only one of your comment that suggests you conceive of these as pointers to two such hash tables (rather than say being temporary variables recording non-NULL elements during iteration through the hash table).  They should be BST**, as they point to the first BST* in the hash table.  But, this is a very dangerous way to implement your hash tables, as the client is using a pointer to the hash table rather than a pointer to some class that provides a safe implementation of the hash table concept.  With such a pointer, all they can do is index to a specific BST, but there's no association with the functions that you intend to maintain the hash table, nor the variables that track how many buckets it currently has space for, how many elements it contains, etc..  You should put your arrays into a class that provides all this; there are lots of design decisions, but it should look something like this:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
class Hash
{
  public:
    Hash() : p_(NULL), size_(0), num_buckets_(0) { }

    // find/make entry for Key, giving read/write access to the current/a-default value
    Value& operator[](const Key&);        
    const Value& operator[](const Key&) const;

    // try to find an entry, throw an exception if not found...
    Value& at(const Key&);
    const Value& at(const Key&) const;

    // report whether a key is already in the hash table...
    bool has_key(const Key&) const;

    int size() const;

  private:
    BST* p_;
    int num_buckets_;
    int size_;
};
```

(yet again, I can only recommend that you first try this with p_ replaced with that vector of maps).

> The second point is memcpy, which I'm not being allowed to do by the compiler.
>
> memcpy(prevData[x], currData[x], sizeof(BST) * height);
>
> Complains about
>
> error C2664: 'memcpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'BST' to 'void *' 
>   No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or 
>   the operator cannot be called

It's a very bizarre request to copy everything from one bucket in one hash table into the same bucket in another hash table.  If, for example, the number of buckets differs or the hash function differs then you'll probably corrupt the destination bucket.  Anyway, I suggest you implement a BST class with value semantics (i.e. a copy constructor and operator= that replicates an existing tree).  Then you can simply use:

```
prevData.buckets[x] = currData.buckets[x];
```

(note: operator should look up in the hash table, and given the key type ought to be able to be int, you don't want to use the same notation for copying entire buckets - you can't overload a function if both have the same signature.  That's why here I show buckets being the exposed container of BSTs - exposing this breaks encapsulation; in real classes you just don't want users even aware of the buckets (or BSTs for that matter)).

Comment: Yeah I wish I could use something like that, but the entire task was to use a custom hash table, chosen hash function, with binary search tree in the table itself. We're not actually allowed to use STL for most things.

Comment: @shrodes: "We're not actually allowed to use STL for most things." ARGH! Bad! Run away! D: The STL is the single most important thing to learn in C++, if only because it's a great example of interface design.

Comment: I can accept you not using the STL as anything but a stepping stone, but must insist that it's the most practical way for you to break this problem down into manageable chunks.  Once you've built something to control a vector of maps, then replace first the vector and then the map with your own implementation.